# How to pass props with cloneElement to Route's component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Say routes are

```
<App>
  <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
</App>
```

Inside App.js I have following

```
React.Children.map(props.children, function (child) {
       return React.cloneElement(child, {
          foo: 'bar'
       })
});
```

But `foo: bar` does not appear inside `Login` component's props.

If I replace `<Route path='/login' component={Login}/>` with `<Login />` then I get `foo: bar` prop there.

My question is how can I pass props to App children (`Route`) so that those props get passed to a corresponding `component`.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. `foo: 'bar'` from App results something like `<Route foo="bar" />` I want that to be reflected in what's in `component=`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it applies to your use case, but `<Route>` comes equipped with a [render prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/render-func):

```
<App>
  <Route 
    path='/login' 
    render={routerProps => (
      <Login 
        {...routerProps} 
        foo='bar' />
    )} />
</App>
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand it's possible to reformat my children iteration, remove `props.component` property from `child` and replace it with `render`, but I'm looking for a solution where those props would apply to component without going this way.

Comment: @David, I've found the `React.Children` method viable only in limited cases; as soon as you need to pass a prop more than one level deep (ie. from `App` to `Route` to `Login`), it gets messy and there's usually a better solution, especially if the intermediary component isn't yours (ie. `Route`). You might want to look into [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) although my guess is it's overkill for what you need. Otherwise, you might be able to create a wrapper for `Route` and use `React.Children.map` within it to pass down the props (in addition to the sample code you provided).

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out above, the nesting level must only be one level to achieve the desired results.

I solved this by wrapping the Route component with a functional component say `RouteWrapper`, since the cloned props will be available to this `RouteWrapper` component.

Then from within the `RouteWrapper` component, I accessed the props as usual and passed it to my component.

```
<Component {...props} foo={props.foo} />
```

.

In general, with the content of `App.js` as being constant, you should have in addition

```
const RouteWrapper = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: RouteProps) => {  
  const { foo, ...otherProps } = rest;

  return (
    <Route
      {...otherProps}
      render={(props) => (
           return <Component {...props} foo={foo} />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

```
<App>
  <RouteWrapper path='/login' component={Login}/>
</App>
```